# Specifying the values of two elements in an If Statement by (separate) classes and/or data-values

Tags: javascript, if-statement, this, equals, key-value

*My apologies for writing such a lengthy question but I was asked to clarify several details about the function*

What would be the correct way to add another element to these If Statements if I want to call it by class or data-name (or another method which doesn't require creating separate If Statements for each element which will utilize it)?

The function is used on pairs of 2 interconnected elements (who's classes are complaint and ranking). The name of the 1rst Element matches the data-name of the 2nd Element, and since the function already identifies data-name of "ranking" maybe it can say that the name of the 1rst element = data-name of the 2nd element?

```
if ($(this).val() == 1 && !$(this).data("decrease_priority1")) { ... }
if ($(this).data("decrease_priority1") && $(this).val() != 1) { ... }
```

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**

1rst If Statement - Set element if values are: ".complaint" = "Too_small" **AND** ."ranking" = "1"
2nd If Statement - Update element if values are: ".complaint" = "Too_small" **OR** ."ranking" = "1"

This 2nd element is the value of the select tag under the .complaint class, however there are several element with the same class so I need a way to specify which one it is. I'm trying to avoid using ID's because there are 25 Select elements (so well over 100 combinations).

**Method I've Tried**

This doesn't work properly (It doesn't accept input unless the 1rst pair (Shoulders) is selected before the 2nd pair (Waist))

```
if ($(".complaint select").val() === "Too_small" && $(this).val() == 1 && !$(this).data("increase_priority1")) 
{ ... }

if ($(this).data("increase_priority1") && ($(this).val() != 1 || $(".complaint select").val() != "Too_small")) 
{ ... }
```

**What the function does**

The purpose of this Change function is to take all the complaint names selected (i.e. Shoulders, Waist) and group them into actions (i.e. increase or decrease) by ranking, so there are different functions that get called for the various combinations - in this case "Too_small" AND "1".  This snippet adds values to "increase_priority1" when the user selects both a complaint and ranks the importance level of the issue, and removes the value when the user changes either element.

If you want to see this in context, I created 2 fiddles. The first is of the existing script http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/vWLEn/171/ and the second is a working example of what I'm trying to do but it uses ID's to do so http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/gYtZw/61/

Javascript

```
var $increase_priority1 = $(".increase_priority1");
// variables for other issues and priority levels go here

$(".ranking").change(function () {
    var name = $(this).data("name"); // Gets data-name of ".ranking" 

    // Sets & Unsets increase_priority1

    // I need to change this to state If values are "Too_small" AND "1" AND (...)  
    if ($(this).val() == 1 && !$(this).data("increase_priority1")) {
        //rank is 1, and not yet added to priority list
        $("<option>", {text: name, val: name}).appendTo($increase_priority1);
        $(this).data("increase_priority1", true); // flag as a priority item
    }
    //If either ranking or complaint value changes 
    if ($(this).data("increase_priority1") && $(this).val() != 1) {
        //is in priority list, but now demoted
        $("option[value=" + name + "]", $increase_priority1).remove();
        $(this).removeData("increase_priority1"); // no longer a priority1 item
    }
    // Similar If Statements go here to set & unset elements for other priority types
});
```

If the value of $increase_priority1 is "Shoulders", complaint was Shoulders too small (select name=Shoulders value=Too_small), and it was assigned a level 1 priority (select class="ranking shoulders" value=1).

HTML

```
<label>To Increase - 1rst Priority
<select name="modify_increase_1rst[]" class="increase_priority1" multiple></select></label>    
<span class="complaint"><label>Shoulders</label>
<select name=Shoulders><option value="null">Select</option><option value="Too_small">Too Small</option><option value="Too_big">Too Big</option><option value="Too_expensive">Too expensive</option>   
</select></span>
<label>Ranking</label>
<select name="importance_bother_shoulders" class="ranking shoulders" data-name="Shoulders">
    <option value="Null">Select</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @Lorax for helping me figure this out :-)

I've included the final code below and created a working example of it at http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/6YnQd/42/

Javascript

```
$('.complaint select.complaintOpt').change(function() {
var $container = $(this).parent(),
    $item = $container.find('.complaintItem'),
    itemId = $item.attr('id'),
    itemVal = $item.val(),
    itemText = $item.find('option[value=' + itemVal + ']').html(),
    rank = $container.find('.complaintRanking').val();    
// Ignore if not a complete complaint
if((itemVal == 'Null') || (rank == 'Null')) {
    return;
}    
// Remove any existing complaint
$('select.priorityIssue option.' + itemId).remove();    
var $selectedOption = $item.find('option:selected');
var targetBase = '';
if($selectedOption.hasClass('goal-increase')) {
    targetBase = '#priorityIncrease';
}
else if($selectedOption.hasClass('goal-decrease')) {
    targetBase = '#priorityDecrease';
}    
if(targetBase != '') {
    // Add new complaint
    $(targetBase + rank + 'Issues')
        .append($('<option>' + $item.attr('name') + '</option>').addClass(itemId));
}
});
```

HTML

```
<label>To Increase </label><br/>
<label for="priorityIncrease1Issues">First Priority</label>
<select name="modify_increase_1rst[]" id="priorityIncrease1Issues" class="priorityIssue" multiple></select>
<label for="priorityIncrease2Issues">Second Priority</label>
<select name="modify_increase_2nd[]" id="priorityIncrease2Issues" class="priorityIssue" multiple></select>
<br/>
<label>To Decrease </label><br/>
<label for="priorityDecrease1Issues">First Priority</label>
<select name="modify_decrease_1rst[]" id="priorityDecrease1Issues" class="priorityIssue" multiple></select>
<label for="priorityDecrease2Issues">Second Priority</label>
<select name="modify_decrease_2nd[]" id="priorityDecrease2Issues" class="priorityIssue" multiple></select>
<br />
<div class="complaint">
<label for="shoulders">Shoulders</label>
<select name=Shoulders id="shoulders" class="complaintOpt complaintItem">
    <option value="Null">Select</option>
    <option value="too_big" class="goal-decrease">Too Big</option>
    <option value="too_small" class="goal-increase">Too Small</option>
</select>    
<label for="shouldersRanking">Ranking</label>
<select name="importance_bother_shoulders" id="shouldersRanking" class="complaintOpt complaintRanking">
    <option value="Null">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding your question a bit confusing, but

```
$(".ranking, .complaint select")
```

referring to two different elements there seems a bit scary with all of your use of $(this) within the function, as well as the fact that from within the selected .complaint select you've brought in to the jQuery factory, you're again calling all

```
$('.complaint select')
```

in your first if statement. That jQuery factory call pulls in an array of all of your .complaint select elements, so, checking .val() on it probably has undesired results. I'm sure you intend to check $(this).val() instead, or at least target only one .complaint select element, and not the entire array. If you want to check the entire array, you should investigate using .each().

More along the lines of what you're trying to do? Again, it's very hard to decipher what you're actually trying to do here between confusion about the code (it's very haphazardly) and confusion about the application purpose itself. This is moreso conceptual to show you how to separate these elements. You need to modularize them, they shouldn't share any concerns:

```
$(".complaint select").change(function() {
     var name = $(this).data("name"); //get priority name    

     // Why was it && before? It's either Too_small or 1 or "Too_small" == 1 so
     // you don't have to check twice for the same thing
     if (($(this).val() === "Too_small" || $(this).val() == 1)  
         &&!$('.ranking').data("increase_priority1")) {
        //rank is 1, and not yet added to priority list
        $("<option>", {text:name, val:name}).appendTo($increase_priority1);
        // .complaint select does not contain a data "increase priority"
        //$(this).data("increase_priority1", true); //flag as a priority item
});

$('.ranking').change(function(){
    if ($(this).data("increase_priority1") &&
    ($(this).val() != 1)) {
        $(".complaint select").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "Too_small"){
            //is in priority list, but now demoted
            $("option[value=" + name + "]", $increase_priority1).remove();
            $(this).removeData("increase_priority1"); //no longer a priority item
        }
    }     
});
```

Comment: You're right, I definitely only want to check the value of one .complaint select element at a time (for example <select name=Shoulders>). My intention with calling $(".ranking, .complaint select") is to trigger the function if either of these changes so that the values in the elements being set/unset is updated when either the complaint or ranking changes. (Cont. in next Comment because of size constraints)

Comment: I take it that I’m going about this the wrong way :-( What would be the correct way to specify the values of 2 elements by class in an If statement when they have different classes (or another method like data-value, which doesn't require customizing the code for each element which will utilize it)?

Comment: Check my edit and see if that helps u more. Trying to show you how to separate the elements a little bit so $(this) works the way you want it to, and so that you can see a use of $.each() to verify each individual element of .complaint select

Comment: My apologies if my code is confusing, but it's a compilation of several people's assistance here and in the jQuery forum and I've probably done a poor job combining it all. But now I understand why you were confused :-( The purpose of this is to take all the complaint names selected (i.e. Shoulders, Waist) and group them into actions (i.e. increase or decrease) by ranking, so there are different functions that get called for the various combinations - in this case "Too_small" AND "1". If seeing a working example using id's would help, a fiddle's at http://jsfiddle.net/chayacooper/gYtZw/61/

Comment: I also edited my question as well as the notes in the code so hopefully it'll be much clearer now

Comment: I tried using your code, but it doesn't set the element increase_priority1. What the function is supposed to do is set increase_priority1 to Shoulders" if complaint was Shoulders too small (select name=Shoulders value=Too_small), and it was assigned a level 1 priority (select class="ranking shoulders" value=1).